# Why there is deductions in point

Tags: discussion

I just check my account and saw mysterious deductions of points as shown below:

[image]

I saw these and there is no downvote; is it because of the fact that some user might have upvoted and now they are no more a user (closed their accounts) with stackexchange or is it something else that we as a user might need to take care?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means someone has removed their upvote on your question or answer.

For example here is what happen when I remove (and add back) my upvote to your answer on the [Server Issues with Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/991/server-issues-with-tridion-2011-sp1-hr1/993#993) question:

[image: effect of removing an up vote]

If the change in Rep had been because of a user being deleted you would see a notification saying so.

Comment: Thanks, my mistake, I overlooked...it is the un-upvote action will do this..